# long title without verb

Tags: sentence-construction, writing, academic-writing

As a non-native English speaker I know that English requires verbs in every sentence, but I don't know if it is the case for the long title (a title of a subsection in academic article).

**Example for long title**

> Best fruits—oranges, apples, and peaches

**Is better to add "are" to the subtitle?**

> Best fruits are oranges, apples, and peaches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, titles (whether of books, films, articles, chapters, sections) are more often single phrases (often noun phrases, but also other types) than full sentences.

I'd have to see the context to know what is best in your example, because it appears to be stating a conclusion, rather than just a single phrase. I think I would go for *Best fruits: oranges, apples, and peaches* with a colon, but it depends a bit on what it is trying to say about the section which follows.

Comment: thanks, what is the difference between Em dash (—) and colon (:)? according wikipedia one can use Em dash as colon

Comment: Dashes and colons are discussed extensively in other questions.

Comment: @Dan, but in the current example ona can use Em dash (—) well?